# ASP.NET MVC - Communication of service layer and EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my MVC application I have this flow:

```
Views <- Controller -> Service layer -> Repository layer -> EF
```

I have some questions about what is the best practise to have between Controller and Service layer. My Controller is in the `Project.Web`, Service Layer in the `Project.Domain`.

I want to get list of 10 popular products from my database, so in my `ProductService` I have method `GetPopularProducts` where I use my CrudService `GetAll` method. 
There is my first question. What is the best practise to get only needed part of entity? In `ProductService` where I operate on full entity or in `CrudService` where I should have information from ProductService about select fields and Take(10) ?

Next, List is returning to the Controller. I have `ProductDetailViewModel`. Where should I map `Product` entity to `ProductDetailViewModel`? In the Controller or in my `ProductService`?

I ask because I dont want to pass my Product entity with 100 fields through my every layer (I need only 10 fields). How I can do that? From where CRUDService should get the information which fields I need? From ProductService? 
My ProductDetailViewModel with needed 10 fields I keep in `Project.Web`, because my View is using it, so I can map my entity only after returning List from my Service. This is good idea?

Comment: Does your repository return IQueryable or do you return a list of materialised objects?  It sounds like your repository is returning ALL entities then you're selecting only the popular ones in the Service layer.  Also does ProductService derive from CrudService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

One option is to create repositories for small (not business logic) operations. Such as GetTopProducts(int count) and use repositories in your service.

It will be better to not use repositories directly (better for unit tests or if you plan in future to change ORM). Instead use interfaces and dependency injection (from your MVC app).

Example:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
   Product GetTopProducts(int count);
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public Product GetTopProducts(int count)
    {
       // EF select goes here
    }
}

public class ProductService
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public Product GetTopProducts()
    {
       // Business logic goes here...
       productRepository.GetTopProducts(10);
       // Business logic goes here...
    }
}


public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private ProductService productService;
    public ProductController(ProductService productService)
    {
       this.productService = productService;
    }

    public ActionResult Products()
    {
       productService.GetTopProducts();
       return View();
    }
}
```

Note: There are many IoC containers for dependency injections. for example [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! But I still have one question about mapping. What is the best practise for returning only needed fields ?
In ProductRepository should I return IEnumerable<Product> where in Select statement I put my 10 needed fields? And in Controller I should map this result on my List<ProductViewModel> which also have 10 fields in Product obejct?

Comment: In general, yes it's better to keep entity models and view models separate. For example, entity model's have navigation properties which in some cases can cause serialization problem (circular dependencies). So it's better to keep view model as clean as possible.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But it is a good idea to return whole Product entity object with only 10 needed fields (rest will be null)? Maybe better idea is to create DTO object in Project.DAL (or Project.Domain - what do you think?) and return it to Controler. In the Controler then I will make mapping between DTO Product and ProductView Model. But in this case I have many models for one operation.

Comment: Easiest way is to create entity model clones (call them business/domain models) and return them from repositories. Service also returns domain models. Controllers are calling service functions, converting them to view models and passing to view.

But as I said in my answer, it all depends on your requirements. You maybe are creating very small project where such complex layers and conversions between models are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should better create a method that directly asks for the 10th from the controller to the EF. Then in EF, you just select the 10th asked!

GetPopularProducts  must return only 10 items, not all! In other words, when you ask for your 10 product, there mist be 10 products that must be returned from theDB. I can advice you to make kind of GetPopularProduct(int numberOfProducts) method to be more flexible :-)